# Check boxes and search Bar

Tags: usability, search, lists, ux-designer

I have a list with multiple select(checkbox) and also a search feature for it.

Case :
On the list appearing, I select two fields in the list and then search for another field. The field I checked earlier now vanishes.

Should I show the user the selected contacts separately or is there a better UX for this problem.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of the interaction? What happens after the searching/selection?

Comment: We have a recruitment application. We will multi-select Candidates and add them to a process.It can be interview or evaluation or so on.

Comment: If you posted a screenshot or mockup it would be easier to understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically 3 options (As the user base is not clear from the question, Im not able to select the best one). All 3 options support search + multiselect.

**OPTION 1:** This type of multi-select works well when the average number of users selected is less. The selected items are shown as chips.
[image]

**OPTION 2:** This type of control can be used when the character length of each item is large. Here, instead of the item itself, the number of items selected is shown.
 [image]

**OPTION 3:** And the last one would be the typical grid layout.
i) A 'select' trigger could be given with each item. Once clicked, the item would jump out of the grid to another section.
ii) Checkboxes with each item in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the **checkbox labels to be long** (though option 1 is not very usable) I would suggest two options based on what is the desired complexity of the search (over a complex set of metadata or just over a list of strings):

1. using a **two column layout** as in Storify. Try logging in Storify and creating a story to see what I'm talking about.
2. A ready-to-use **duallist** widget like this one (highly customizable, also):

https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

Recruiters may select a list of candidates by double clicking, or selecting and using the arrow, or bulk selecting on a filtered subset with the double arrow ;)